# Ionic 4 app shows api data in browser but on device it doen't shows api data

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I run Ionic 4 app, the browser shows api data but when i run same app on android device it doen't shows api data.
I am using Laravel as a backend, from where i am fetching api data.
The Ionic info is -

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.5.0 (C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.16.1 (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```

I am really stuck here...

Comment: You must be getting some error, most probably about CORS. Try inspecting your app with chrome.

Comment: I got error on chrome as---    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'website_name_api' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  but this error removed while enabling chrome CORS..

Comment: But when i run this app on android device, it shows nothing.. app data goes blank..

Comment: Most probable issue would be CORS, You will need your backend api to allow requests from your origin.

Comment: Please guide me regarding this sir.. I am using Laravel 5 and mysql as backend..

Comment: See this link: https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1

Comment: Still no success sir....

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is Cors you can install middleware in laravel to avoide the problem 
Or you can test your application in the chrome disable securite

Try to Run :

chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

and test your application in this chrome and let me khnow

Comment: The app runs on chrome but not able to show data on android device....